# InitialState not updated in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to change the state immutably and return a new state but in the UI component new state not changed. The new state values are fetched successfully but not display. I don't understand what is the issue behind.

> Anyone has suggestions share me

Here is my reducer:

```js
import * as actionTypes from './actions';

const initialState = {
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "accordion1", content: () => {}, status: 1},
        {id: 2, name: "accordion2", content: () => {}, status: 0},
        {id: 3, name: "accordion3", content: () => {}, status: 0},
    ]
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    debugger;
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE:
            debugger;
            var newData = state.data;
            for(var i= 0; i<newData.length; i++) {
                newData[i].status = newData[i].status === 1 ? 0 : 1
                
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                data: newData
            }
        default: 
        return state; 
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

Here is my UI component were not update:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../store/actions';

class Accordion extends Component {
    render() {
        debugger;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.accordions.map((accordion, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <div>{accordion.status}</div>
                            <div className={`accordion ${accordion.status}`} onClick={this.props.expandAccordion}>
                                {accordion.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className="panel">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        accordions: state.data
    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        expandAccordion: () => dispatch({type: actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE})
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Accordion);
```

Comment: You’re mutating state. newData points to the same Array as state.data. This means that you’re actually returning the same state object - so React doesn’t know that it needs to re-render. Try to find a way to avoid the mutation.

Comment: try changing  ```var newData =state.data.map(data => {
data.status = data.status === 1 ? 0 : 1;
return {...data};
});```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually mutating the state. Try this...

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions';
    
    const initialState = {
      data: [
          {id: 1, name: "accordion1", content: () => {}, status: 1},
          {id: 2, name: "accordion2", content: () => {}, status: 0},
          {id: 3, name: "accordion3", content: () => {}, status: 0},
      ]
    }
    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
          case actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE:
            return {
              ...state,
              data: state.data.map((acdnObj) => {
                return {
                  ...acdnObj,
                  status: acdnObj.status === 1 ? 0 : 1,
                }
              }),
            }
          default: 
          return state; 
      }
    }
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is in the following lines:

```
var newData = state.data;
for(var i= 0; i<newData.length; i++) {
  newData[i].status = newData[i].status === 1 ? 0 : 1             
}
```

Why?
Since basically, when you assign `var newData = state.data;` you actually copy the object **reference**, and by that, you don't keep it immutable, and as far for React, which makes shallow comparing, it never changed.

One possible solution would be to change this code to an immutable update:

```
const newData = state.data.map((entry) => ({...entry, status: entry.status === 1 ? 0 : 1}));

return {
  ...state,
  data: newData
}
```

P.S: If you want to get smarty pants, you can use XOR for your status update: `({...entry, status: entry.status ^ 1})`